# angularJS what's a good way to put dictionary in input

Tags: angularjs

I have a dictionary of data in the controller and I'm displaying it using `ng-repeat`. The `key` is the Title and the `value` is placed as the `value` field of an `input`. I want the user to be able to edit the values and then submit the form. What's the best way I can handle all the input? I've tried `ng-model` but I can't change the values of the dictionary directly so I'm leaning towards making another dictionary to store the new data. That doesn't seem very efficient though so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

edit: I have this interface and add some values.

```
export interface Iint {
    [title: string] : string;
}
```

this is in the constructor

```
this.hashMap : Iint = {};
this.hashMap["Next Title"] = "data";
this.hashMap["Next Value"] = "more data;
```

In the `html` I want each of the `values` (data, more data) to appear in it's own input  text box where the user can edit and change the values in the dictionary. I need validation and other things before the user can save and update the data so I'm unsure of if I should be making a duplicate array.

Comment: What do you mean a dictionary ? Could you provide an example ?

Comment: edited with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example out. I implemented it in Angular v1 before you edited your answer.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9Y33BDQTngPZx2Vpx5Zz?p=preview

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.dict = {
    "Title1" : "Hello World !",
    "Title2" : "Beautiful day",
    "Title3" : "How about that!?"
  };

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    console.log($scope.dict);
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.dict));
  };
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Dictionary Inputs</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in dict">
        {{key}} : <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.dict[key]"> 
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <div>
         $scope.dict : {{dict}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Implementing it in Angular v2 might be on similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get ngRepeat to iterate over the properties of an object using the following syntax:

`<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>`

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties